# JList - locationToIndex() always returning the same index for mouse location in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlist, point

I'm testing around a bit with JLists and I wanted a little window to pop up on MouseEnter and show the content of the list entry the mouse was hovering over; also the window disposes on MouseExit.
So far this worked great, but for it to update the mouse has to exit and re-enter.

Now I wanted to make it work in a parallel Thread and update the window all the time, so it would change without me having to exit first, and tried this:

```
     public void run() {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                String text = list.getModel().getElementAt(
                        list.locationToIndex(p));
                lab.setText(text);
            }
```

But it always only shows the content of the last entry in the list, no matter where the mouse is.
If I print out `text`it's always the same content, even though the mouse position changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()` gives the location of the mouse within the context of the screen.

`JList#locationToIndex` expects the point to be within the context of the `JList`.

This can be a little confusing at first, but, basically, when dealing with functionality like this, components except the point to be within their coordinate context, where 0x0 is the top, left corner of the component.  This actually makes life a lot easier, as you don't constantly need to be translating between screen and component coordinates...

You will need to first convert the `Point` to component coordinates...

```
SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p, list);
```

Then request the index of represented by the point

Also note that Swing is not thread safe, that means that you should only ever access or modify UI components from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

So this makes...

```
String text = list.getModel().getElementAt(
                    list.locationToIndex(p));
lab.setText(text);
```

...very dangerous.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Without knowning exactly what you're trying to do it's difficult to provide alternative suggestions, but you might consider using a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and/or [`MouseMotionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html), registered to the `JList`, instead

The immediate benefit of this is that the `MouseEvent` is already converted to the coordinate space of the component that triggered the event

Comment: Another quick question, what could you suggest for me to make the window change it's position dynamically with the mouse's position, so it doesn't stay at the position where it first appeared?
Using window.setLocation(p) makes it appear and disappear very quickly and does not look good, is there a good way for this at all?

Comment: Honestly, the best solution is `setLocation` the question is, what are you trying to do

Comment: +1 usage of ListSelectionListener instead of MouseWhatever, but HightLigter could be works this way, maybe talking about renderers concept

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead yours code

```
        Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        list.setSelectedIndex(list.locationToIndex(p));

        String text = list.getSelectedValue().toString();
        lab.setText(text);
```

Comment: Where does `e` come from?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void JLISTE_clicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(evt)){
        if (evt.getComponent()==JLISTE){
            int idx = JLISTE.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());
            System.out.println("Index rightclicked : " + idx); // testing
            JLISTE.setSelectedIndex(idx);
        }
    }
....
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.